# Verifying examples of definition of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, self-learning

> Let K be a field containing F as a subfield, written as $K/F$. Call $F$ the base field of $K/F$ and $K$ the extension field of $K/F$.
>
> Definition: Let $K/F$ be an extension of fields. K is a vector space over $F$ by restriction of scalars. Denote the dimension, $\text{dim}_F K$, of $K$ as an F-vector space by $[K:F]$ and call it the degree of $K/F$. We call $K/F$ a finite extension if $[K:F]$ is finite, and an infinite extension otherwise.

This is copied from an Abstract Algebra Lecture Notes. It gives a few examples to show this definition.

> Example: 1). $F/F$ iss a finite extension of degree one; 2).$\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is a finite extension of degree two; 3). $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite extension.

I am not sure how to verify those examples. Specifically why is $\text{dim}_F F$ of degree 1, $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ of degree 2 and such? Need help with walking through the idea of checking those examples. Appreciate it!

Comment: The field $F$ is a vector space over itself of dimension one (a basis could be $\{1\}$). Since $\mathbb{C}$ is spanned by $\{1, i\}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{1, i\}$ are linearly independent (whatever specific definitions of $i$ you are using) over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ has degree two. Suppose $[\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite then $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$  for some real (algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$) $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, a contradiction.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang That's more than helpful. Thanks!